# How to get stripe public key when you have secret key?

Tags: stripe-payments

Before changing stripe credentials and setting it up on my platform's account, I want to check if they are good. Obviously to check secret key you need to just make any api request that requires auth. But is there any way to check public key using stripe api and valid secret key?

Comment: You could use it on an endpoint that requires a public key. Secret key is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While I'd suggest just using it for a test integration, you can validate it with any one of the API endpoints also designed for interaction with Stripe.js, such as [creating a person token](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_person):

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
  -u pk_test_123:
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'person[first_name]=test'
```